# Is it possible to reload Visual Studio Image Service? (or Icons of my Extension do not load)

Tags: c#, icons, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm experimenting with the concept of custom Image Moniker and the Visual Studio Image Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/image-service-and-catalog?view=vs-2022) in my Extension. I am supporting VS2017 to VS2022+. I followed the documentation, added my .png/.xaml as ressource, created my ImageManifest file, included the Iconmapping in a csv and placed both in my Extension folder.

After installation, all icons are loaded correctly. They are displayed in the toolbar as well as in the commands (VSCT reference). I can also load the bitmaps via the `IVsImageService2`.
My problem is that this only works on the first start after installation. From the second start, it seems that Visual Studio can no longer find the files. The toolbar remains empty and the `IVsUIObject uIObj = imageService.GetImage(myCustomMoniker, attributes)` call returns null. It works for KnownMonikers, which I also used in my extension.

I assume that my package in Visual Studio is loaded either too early or too slowly and the order is not correct. As far as I know, the package is loaded very late at the first start after the installation of a package.

Is it possible to initialize the ImageService or the package again or determine the sequence?

Does anyone know these problems with the VsImageService?

I am not yet using an asynchronous package. Could this also be a problem?

I already tried to reload the extension, reinstalled, with devenv.exe /setup, etc.
It didn't helped.

Comment: After some investigation I realized that the ImageService is looking for the resource in the extension directory. If you have entered a different codebase in the pkgdef, the ImageService does not work.